# How do I convert this FK leg to IK without getting rid of animation

Tags: animation, baking, inverse-kinematics, motion-capture, forward-kinematics

[image]

I have this character here that has motion capture on him but I want the legs to be put into IK instead of using FK without getting rid of the motion capture I got from Mixamo. I've tried "baking" but I don't know how that works, lol.

On a similar note does anyone think that I could just upload the character to Mixamo with an IK rig instead of having to change it at this stage?

Thanks for reading my post, here is the blend file if you need it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an IK rig on Mixamo, you have to convert it at this stage.

This is the procedure:

- In edit mode duplicate the foot bones (shift D), and put them in a different bone layer, for easier manipulation.
- Clear their parenting (Alt P)
- In pose mode set a copy transform constraint, in world space, targeting the respective Mixamo foot bone.
- go to menu - Pose - Animation - Bake action, and check all preferences buttons
- change the parenting of the toe bones from Mixamo feet to new ik feet
- select the mesh and change the name of feet vertex groups from Mixamo names to new bones names
- Delete the Mixamo feet bones
- set an IK constraint on the calf bones, pointing at the Ik feet, setting the chain lenght to 2.

Now you have  working IK legs, without toe roll controls. To control the toe is a bit more complicated, but the basic concept is the same.

[image]